# PHP variable unexpected result

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
include_once("../content/includes/connect.php");
include_once("_functions.php");

//TODO: support sending variables
$check = true;
$callback = "error";

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: {$key}<br>";
    echo "Value: {$value}<br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(checkRules("register", $key, $value));
    echo "</pre>";
    list($pass, $errormessage) = checkRules("register", $key, $value);
    echo "Pass: {$pass}<br>";
    echo "Errormessage: {$errormessage}<br><br>";
    if (!$pass) {
        $check = false;
        $callback = "error";
        break;
    }
}

if ($check) {
    $callback = "register_success";
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "callback" => $callback
));

SQL::close();
```

And this gives me the following HTML page:

```
Key: email
Value: a@a.aa

Array
(
    [pass] => 1
    [errormessage] => 
)

Pass:
Errormessage:

{"callback":"error"}
```

Now I do not get why the `list($pass, $errormessage) = checkRules("register", $key, $value);` does not work, when I clearly see that with `print_r()` it has the results.

Comment: First, what is the real error message? Second, what do you mean *don't work*? The error is on the call of the function or inside it?

Comment: What does var_dump prints? It looks like **pass** is a boolean. Please also paste the code for **checkRules**.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown He's not getting an error message. His problem is that the variables are not getting the values returned by the function when he uses `list($pass, $errormessage)` assignment.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown The question is very clear if you read it.

Comment: @meagar if he's asking, is not *very clear*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list(...) = array` assignment only works when the array is indexed, but `checkRules` returns an associative array.

You need to write:

```
$result = checkRules("register", $key, $value);
$pass = $result['pass'];
$errormessage = $result['errormessage'];
```

or change `checkRules` to return an indexed array (not my preference -- indexed arrays should only be used for uniform data).

You could also write:

```
list($pass, $errormessage) = array_values(checkRules("register", $key, $value));
```

but I think it's generally poor practice to depend on the order of elements in an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning an array with string keys. You need to return an array with numeric indices instead, as `list` expects.

`checkRules` should be returning `[1, ""]`, **not** `array("pass" => 1, "errormessage" => "")`.

Answer (score 1):

Change line like this:

```
list($pass, $errormessage) = array_values(checkRules("register", $key, $value));
```

`list` can't work with associative arrays :)

Comment: Definitely won't work. `extract` pulls the variables out into the local namespace, the result can't be assigned to `list`. This will just give you a syntax error.

Comment: This can work with if you use `array_values` instead of `extact`.

Comment: Thank you, guys, messed this funcion up in my mind. Updated the answer.